# Homekit trigger, how to call it

Tags: swift, triggers, homekit

I'm watching WWDC 2018 videos about Homekit and more precisely about triggers. I'm trying to use this snippet to create a sunset presence trigger. I would like turnOn a light when this function is running. I already have the turnOn function working but how to implement it in this trigger ? Thanks in advance!

```
func createSunsetPresenceTrigger(withName name: String, actionSet: HMActionSet, home: HMHome) {
        var offset = DateComponents()
            offset.minute = -10

        let sunsetEvent = HMSignificantTimeEvent(significantEvent: .sunset, offset: offset)

        let presence = HMPresenceEvent(presenceEventType: .atHome, presenceUserType: .currentUser)
        let predicate = HMEventTrigger.predicateForEvaluatingTrigger(withPresence: presence)
        let trigger = HMEventTrigger(name: name, events: [sunsetEvent], predicate: predicate)

        home.addTrigger(trigger) { (error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }

            trigger.addActionSet(actionSet) { error in
                guard error == nil else { /* Handle error */ return }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an **HMActionSet** with power characteristic value of that light set to '**true**' and add with this function of **HMTrigger**

```
open func addActionSet(_ actionSet: HMActionSet, completionHandler completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
```